# Why vim keeps returning error "E714: List required" when I'm already feeding a list to it?

Tags: vimscript

I have this snippet:

```
let g:git_file_prefix = ['M','A','R','D','U','?']

function! Colorize(str)
  let index = 0
  for file in a:str
   call add(a:str[index], '$(tput 37)')
   let index = index + 1
 endfor
endfunction

call Colorize(g:git_file_prefix)
```

As you can see, the global variable `git_file_prefix` has already been defined as a list.
Yet vim returns `E714 List required` on line calling the `add()` function.

What might be wrong in this snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the doc [`:h add()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#add%28%29) says:

```
add({list}, {expr})                 *add()*
        Append the item {expr} to {list}.
```

The first argument of the function `add()` should be a list but you give it `a:str[index]` which is an *element* of the list (so a string) not the list itself.

If you want to concatenate `'$(tput 37)'` to the element of the list you probably want to use `let a:str[index] .= '$(tput 37)'`

Comment: You're right! I can't believe I missed that!. thanks mate +1.. still have to wait few more minutes to accept.

Comment: just one more thing, how can i prepend a value to a string?

Comment: @JohnFredFadrigalan You're welcome :) Also if I can give you a little advice, naming your list `str` doesn't sound like a good idea: 1) `str` is not really a name which conveys what the variable contains and 2) the worst part it is misguiding about the type of the variable. And about your for loop which uses an index and do the same thing with all the items, you probably want to use [`:h map()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#map%28%29) instead :)

Comment: And to prepend to a string you could use `let str = 'new value' . str` for example

Comment: Thanks! you're really a big help! since i'm a novice in this stuff.. I'll try looking it up!